# UIMapView: User location annotation is white not pulsing blue in iPad only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mapping, mkmapview

I've been working with maps for a while so I understand the basics of what needs to happen to show the user's location

```
map.showsUserLocation = YES; //also have the box checked in .xib
```

set up the locationManager

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {

if (locationManager != nil) {
    return locationManager;
}

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];

return locationManager;
}
```

I've logged and see that I'm hitting the didUpdateUserLocation method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

if (!userLoc)
{
    //NSLog(@"Mapping - didUpdateUserLocation");
    userLoc = userLocation.location;
}

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and I'm also making sure I don't remove the user's annotation

```
if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
```

...so why is the blue dot showing and pulsing on the iPhone, but showing as a white dot only on the iPad?  (Both devices are iOS 7.1.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only iPad's with cellular will have access to the GPS which is what the blue pulsing dot represents in MKMapView. Every iPhone has GPS which is why you are seeing the pulsing dot on that device.

Without cellular (3G/4G/LTE) the iPad can only use WiFi to triangulate position, which is not accurate enough for navigation.

Comment: Haha! I went back to say pretty much what you said to answer my own question.  Interesting that my dot is all white and the Maps app has the pulsing blue dot, but doesn't update user's location..which I unfortunately didn't test.  Should've known that, but if I can't find it on SO, then I'm in a vacuum, devoid of all knowledge of space and time...!

Comment: Funny thing.
I had the same problem on my iphone, which has no sim card installed. So GPS alone is not enough as it seems. Without a sim card installed there is only a white dot showing on my phone.

Comment: unfortunately that is not the solution in my case. Does anyone of you have an other idea why i only have a white dot? Everything else in my app is set up as it should be.